# restricted IP using Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app

I added IP restriction to our org ,however I can log-in using my Salesforce1 app but the access is block using the computer. What I need to do in order to block access in Salesforce1? Attached image

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Oh. This shouldn't happen. Did you try to login using Salesforce1 app after clearing the cache?

Comment: How can I clearing the cache?

Comment: In iOS, there isn't any way. [How to clear cache of a specific application in iOS](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/248930/how-to-clear-cache-of-a-specific-application-in-ios) You might probably want to uninstall the app and then reinstall the same, then try logging in. If it's an Android device, Go to Settings-->App and click Salesforce1 from the list and there's an option to clear app cache. PS: I'm not sure whether this works, but it's worth giving it a try.